# Security issues in web services implemented using Django?

Tags: django, web-services, security

I need to create user authentication and some web services using Django (clients will be Android). My plan is to use built-in Django's authentication, cookie-based sessions and web services RESTFUL with JSON data.

Is there any security issues I should worry about or built-in tools should be ok?

Thanks

Comment: I've used the native auth without any issues. Out company have performed some tests which came out very positive. I would rely more upon the open source code than custom code I would build myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, no. Cookie-based sessions is secure. A lot of sites use built-in Django's authentication and everything ok.